# Maintain nested JSON as String in Dataset Encoding

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

Let's say I have a file containing JSON documents which look something like:

```
{ 
    "name" : "J Smith", 
    "age" : 33, 
    "child" : {
         "name" : "K Smith", 
         "age" : 12
         }
}
```

How can I create an encoder for this which maintains the `child` document without having to create an encoder for that too? Efforts so far look like this:

```
Encoder<Person> personEncoder = Encoders.bean(Person.class);
Dataset<Person> personDs = spark.read().json(EnvironmentProps.RAW_DATA_LOCATION).as(personEncoder);
```

Person class looks like:

```
public class Person {

private String name;
private int age;
private String child; // <- what data type should this be to preserve it?

public Person(){}

public Person(String name, int age, String child){
 ...
}
```

This kinda works, but when I write the file out, the child document comes out as a long array of numbers, what I'd like to do is keep it the same as it went in.

Comment: `private Map child;` (?)

Comment: thank for prompt response - it's now saying the class isn't bean compliant

Comment: ...presume it's talking about the Map class not being bean-compliant rather than my Person class